# How to make an entity unkillable?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I want to protect my custom entity but everyone can kill it. I tried to loop setting health to max, I tried to protect it with events but it could still die.

How to protect it? Or is there any built-in-minecraft method which makes the entity unkillable?​

Comment: How are people killing it? Are they hitting it until it dies, are they in creative, or are they using a command?

Comment: They are in survival and they are hitting it

Comment: What kind of entity are you trying to make unkillable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Invulnerable tag. Spawn the Entity with the extra tag `{Invulnerable:1}`.

Another choice is the resistance potion effect:

```
/effect <Target> minecraft:resistance 1000000 255 true
```